# Key/value pairs in custom widget

Tags: python, django

So let's say I have jQuery convert a simple text input from this

```
<input class='employee_list' name='requestor' type='text' />
```

to this

```
<div name='requestor' class='ajax_picker'>
    <input class='search_box' class='employee_list' name='requestor_text' type='text'/>
    <input class='id' name='requestor' type='hidden' value='' /> 
    <div class='results'></div>
</div>
```

And load the hidden input value with AJAX + JSON.  Problem is, `if form.is_valid() is not True`, then how can I create a custom Widget that will render both values?  Thinking I could do two different fields, but that seems ugly.  I could also customize the form rendering, but that's even worse.  Maybe the form can pass all of the POST data to the widget, but can't seem to figure out how to get that to work.

There must be an elegant way to achieve this!

```
from django import forms

class AjaxPickerWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        # ... now what?
        return super(AjaxPickerWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
```

**My Solution**

Thanks for your help, I took a variant approach.  Since I am using this strictly for Models (hence needing a key/value pair) I made the widget interact directly with the model and create a `data-id` attribute that the jQuery would catch to move to the hidden field.

```
from django import forms

class AjaxPickerModelWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, css_class, queryset, id_name, value_name, attrs={}):
        attrs['class'] = css_class
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.id_name = id_name
        self.value_name = value_name
        super(AjaxPickerModelWidget, self).__init__(attrs=attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs={}):
        try:
            instance = self.queryset.get(**{self.id_name: value})
            attrs['data-id'] = value
            value = getattr(instance, self.value_name)
        except:
            value = ''
        return super(AjaxPickerModelWidget, self).render(name, value,
                                                         attrs=attrs)
```

Comment: When you say "create a custom Widget that will render both values," what do you mean by "both values"?

Comment: The value from the text input and hidden input, cache the search string.  In my case it's an id and str from a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this qualifies as elegant, but how about something like this. Here I'm storing the search string as a property on the widget, and setting the property from the POST data in the form constructor. I'm also using name="foo_picker_text" to indicate the search input for the corresponding input named "foo".

```
class AjaxPickerWidget(HiddenInput):
  search_text_suffix = "_picker_text"

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(AjaxPickerWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.search_text = None

  def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    start = '<div name="%s" class="ajax_picker">' % (name) + \
             '<input class="search_box" name="%s%s" ' % (name, self.search_text_suffix)+ \
             'type="text" value="%s" />' % (self.search_text or "")
    end = super(AjaxPickerWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs) + '</div>'
    return '%s%s' % (start, end)

class MyForm(Form):
  requestor = CharField(widget = AjaxPickerWidget())

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # find picker text in POST data and tell the corresponding widget about it
    for name in self.data:
      if name.endswith(AjaxPickerWidget.search_text_suffix):
        field_name = name.split(AjaxPickerWidget.search_text_suffix)[0]
        self.fields[field_name].widget.search_text = self.data[name]
```

You might have to tweak it a bit to get attributes to show up where you want them, etc. but hopefully this basically does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of calling `is_valid()` on your form create a custom function

```
from django import forms

class AjaxPickerWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return super(AjaxPickerWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
    def validate(self):
        values = self.cleaned_data.items():
        # Modify the values to fit the original form (delete, change etc)
        return whateversleft.is_valid() # Perhaps with some additional checks
```